# TabBarController->viewController send data to tableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a problem with passing array from `UIViewController` to `UITableviewController`
In storyboard I have this:

[image]

I want, if we clicked "send" button then our array from viewController, saved to array in tableViewController

Now I have something like this:

```
-(IBAction)wyslij {
    WynikiTableViewController *wynikiTVC = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    wynikiTVC.viewController = self;
    wynikiTVC.przepisyArray = [mojeArray copy];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

`PrzepisyArray` is my array in `WynikiTableViewController`, and `mojeArray` is my array in ViewController.

I tried also modal, but if I used this, then my TabBarController was hidden.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the answer! :D

It's look like this:

```
-(IBAction)wyslij {
UINavigationController *nav = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
WynikiTableViewController *wynikiTVC = (WynikiTableViewController*) [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

....
}
```